# CE amplifier design for audio amplifier

Tags: amplifier, audio, bjt, simulation, pspice

I am trying to design an audio amplifier which provides a maximum gain of 20dB (or) 10V/V.

For the circuit I designed, the lower half of the amplified signal is being clipped.

I am also attaching the PSPICE student edition schematic file for review sendspace.com/file/5ntjl3

[image: Circuit Schematic]
[image: Output Obtained]

Comment: Please copy and Paste the link. Stack Exchange doesn't allow me to post more than two links. https://www.sendspace.com/file/5ntjl3

Comment: Please observe that the circuit has been clamped. Kindly help with this.

Comment: On what basis did you calculate these resistances?  Set R19=R19 <- 220k to bias near the centre voltage and provide 110k input impedance. The transistor can only handle 200mA so R21 needs to be at least 27.5 ohms. I would set it to at least 2k2, and therefore R16 <- at least 22k to yield the required gain. You need to AC-couple the output. C1 should be 330nF or more: I sincerely hope `100m` (F) is a typo, otherwise you will need a trolley.

Answer (score 1):

Reduce R18 until it stops clipping. Increase R21 because you only want a gain of ten. R21 could be 42 ohms. For a real circuit, both R18 and R19 are way too high for proper thermal stability.

Comment: Could you explain why the output is being clamped. And how could I offset it to 0v

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the design starts with selecting a proper quiescent current Ic.
Then, the next step is to find corresponding resistors Rc (collector) and Re (emitter). Using Ohms law and according to a rule of thumb you can allocate 10% of Vcc to the drop across Re and another 40% of Vcc to the drop across Rc.

Next, calculate the bias voltage divider for producing at the base node the voltage **Vb=(0.7V+IeRe)** folllowing another rule of thumb: The current through the voltage divider should be app. **I1=(6...10)Ib** with Ib=Ic/B.

The voltage gain can be adjusted by shorting the emitter resistor Re (or a part of it!) with a large capacitor Ce.

**EDIT:** The following calculation example shows the feasibility of the proposed step sequence: Combining IcRc=0.4Vcc and gmRc=IcRc/25mV=200 gives a required supply voltage of Vcc=12.5 Volts.

Hence (IcRc=0.4Vcc=5V): Ic=1mA and Rc=5k or Ic=2mA and Rc=2.5k or....